# How does Visual Studio determine whether it has to start MSBuild or not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I've done a lot of MSBuild customization for my C++ projects in the past. The *Input* and *Output* attributes of a MSBuild target are used to determine whether the target has to be executed or not. Additionally Visual Studio uses the .tlog files (located in the intermediate directory) to determine whether MSBuild has to be invoked at all.

Now I'm working on a C# project. I wrote a simple MSBuild target which copies a file to the output directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="CopyMyFile" BeforeTargets="AfterBuild" Inputs="$(ProjectDir)File.dat" Outputs="$(TargetDir)FileRenamed.dat">
    <Copy SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)File.dat" DestinationFiles="$(TargetDir)FileRenamed.dat" OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true">
    </Copy>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

The target works as expected if the build is invoked through MSBuild.exe. The file is copied if the target file does not exist or the source file has been modified.

If I invoke the build inside Visual Studio it does not work as expected. Visual Studio does not invoke MSBuild if I delete the file from the output directory. On the other hand MSBuild is invoked every time I build the project after modifiying the source file even if there are no other changes made.

It seems that Visual Studio just compares every file from a project to the output files (.exe, .dll or .pdb). If any file in the project is newer than the output files, MSBuild is invoked. In my case MSBuild does not update the .exe file, so MSBuild is invoked again and again.

In a C++ project this behaviour is controlled by the .tlog files. Is there anything similar in a C# project?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The .tlog files are not used by MSBuild directly but by Visual Studio to decide whether MSBuild has to be invoked. I used to create my own .tlog files for my custom build targets to control when Visual Studio has to invoke MSBuild and when not. I hope there's a similar technique available for C# projects.

Comment: are you sure? Even when not building C++ projects  with VS but just msbuild tlog files are being created (and likely read in again on the next build)

Comment: You are right. Sorry for the wrong comment. But the assumption that Visual Studio uses the .tlog files to decide whether MSBuild has to be invoked is hopefully still true. But anyway, this is not important. What I need is a way to tell Visual Studio when to invoke MSBuild and when not because Visual Studio doesn't know anything about my custom build targets.

Comment: I don't have time to come up with an answer now but I'm fairly sure VS uses just timestamps to compare files. So you somehow have to instruct it to 'see' your file. To figure out how you can do that you're going to have to look at how, for instance, Content is implemented: if you just add a textfile to the project it's added to the Content ItemGroup and if you set it's CopyToOutputDirectory metadata to PreserveNewest it automatically gets the behaviour you're after, in VS, so there likely is a way to mimick this for custom targets.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be *no, nothing similar to the tlog mechanism*. I am not 100% sure though, also because it's strange you cannot do something quite basic as this as that would mean MS basically ditched the tracker stuff for C# (and similar) projects but didn't replace it with something which can be hooked into by users.

Using procmon you can see VS getting timestamps of output and input files, but nowhere I found a way to interfere with what it treats as input and output files. It looks like VS gets a list of everything included directly in the project file (i.e. Reference/Content/Compile/.. item groups of what is shown in VS), not what is listed in Taget's Inputs/Outputs, and at the start of a build compares timstamps for just those items. If everything (well, everything as far as VS is considered) is up to date no msbuild process is launched for the build.

There is a workaround, though not super nice: if you add a 'dummy' Content item (e.g. Right-click project->Add New Item->Text File) and set it to always be copied (Right-clik text file just added->Properties->Copy to Output Directory->Copy always) then VS will *always* start a build and hence check your target's Inputs vs the Outputs and run if if you deleted FileRenamed.dat.

Comment: I recently came across the [IBuildUpToDateCheckProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.workspace.build.ibuilduptodatecheckprovider(v=vs.150).aspx) interface which addresses this problem. I don't know if this is the way to go. What I don't like is that you have to extend Visual Studio AND MSBuild to hit the target..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43283613 is similar to this. What has been simple in a VS project seems impossible in a C# project without writing VS extensions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is just poorly documented. [This site](http://reedbeta.com/blog/custom-toolchain-with-msbuild/) shows you can easily hook up a command line tool, while lifting on the incremental features of tlog files.

To make sure the information doesn't get lost, I'll just copy over their use case, but looking at that, I think it's easy to transform into your needs. Every occurrence of `dcx` can be replaced by e.g. `data`

## 1. Create a definition `.xml` file

- Define an `ItemType`
- Link a `ContentType` to the `ItemType`
- Hook up a `FileExtension`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProjectSchemaDefinitions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/build/2009/properties">
  <!-- Associate DXCShader item type with .hlsl files -->
  <ItemType Name="DXCShader" DisplayName="DXC Shader" />
  <ContentType Name="DXCShader" ItemType="DXCShader" DisplayName="DXC Shader" />
  <FileExtension Name=".hlsl" ContentType="DXCShader" />
</ProjectSchemaDefinitions>
```

## 2. Create a `.targets` file

- Include the `.xml` definitions file
- Create a `Target` that depends on one of your build hooks (here: `ClCompile`)
- Create an `ItemGroup` in your Target that will serve as the argument to your `CustomBuild`. `Message`, `Command`, `AdditionalInputs` and `Output` are meta-attributes that are relevant.
- Invoke `CustomBuild` with **`MinimalRebuildFromTracking="true"`** and a `TrackerLogDirectory` to contain the `tlog` files. **This part is the magic ingredient** that makes MSBuild skip the build if your dependencies are up-to-date.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Include definitions from dxc.xml, which defines the DXCShader item. -->
    <PropertyPageSchema Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)dxc.xml" />
    <!-- Hook up DXCShader items to be built by the DXC target. -->
    <AvailableItemName Include="DXCShader">
      <Targets>DXC</Targets>
    </AvailableItemName>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target
    Name="DXC"
    Condition="'@(DXCShader)' != ''"
    BeforeTargets="ClCompile">

    <Message Importance="High" Text="Building shaders!!!" />

    <!-- Find all shader headers (.hlsli files) -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <ShaderHeader Include="*.hlsli" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ShaderHeaders>@(ShaderHeader)</ShaderHeaders>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <!-- Setup metadata for custom build tool -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DXCShader>
        <Message>%(Filename)%(Extension)</Message>
        <Command>
          "$(WDKBinRoot)\x86\dxc.exe" -T vs_6_0 -E vs_main %(Identity) -Fh %(Filename).vs.h -Vn %(Filename)_vs
          "$(WDKBinRoot)\x86\dxc.exe" -T ps_6_0 -E ps_main %(Identity) -Fh %(Filename).ps.h -Vn %(Filename)_ps
        </Command>
        <AdditionalInputs>$(ShaderHeaders)</AdditionalInputs>
        <Outputs>%(Filename).vs.h;%(Filename).ps.h</Outputs>
      </DXCShader>
    </ItemGroup>

    <!-- Compile by forwarding to the Custom Build Tool infrastructure,
         so it will take care of .tlogs and error/warning parsing -->
    <CustomBuild
      Sources="@(DXCShader)"
      MinimalRebuildFromTracking="true"
      TrackerLogDirectory="$(TLogLocation)"
      ErrorListRegex="(?'FILENAME'.+):(?'LINE'\d+):(?'COLUMN'\d+): (?'CATEGORY'error|warning): (?'TEXT'.*)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```