# Custom build action properties in a Visual Studio C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

In a Visual Studio C++ project I can define custom build actions and corresponding property rules (see `cl.xml` under the MSBuild folder). How can I create such a rule for a custom build action in a C# project? Under the MSBuild folder there's a the file `Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets` which references `CSharp.ProjectItemsSchema.xaml`, `CSharp.xaml` and `CSharp.BrowseObject.xaml` which looks exacltly like the definitions I need. Using procmon I can see that these files are not accessed at all. What's the correct way to define custom build actions?

To clarify what I want to accomplish here's an example:

1. I add an image file (.png) to the project
2. I have a special image resource 'compiler' the transform the image (this compiler is defined using a msbuild target)
3. I want to change properties of the image file (e.g. target resolution, format, etc.). In a C++ project I can open the file property dialog for this.
   These properties are saved as MSBuild item metadata and forwarded to the MSBuild target.

The resulting project file would contain data like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyImageContent Include="Image.png">
      <OutputName>MyImage.png</OutputName>
      <TargetResX>512</TargetResX>
      <TargetResY>256</TargetResY>
    </MyImageContent>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This additional metadata can easily be used by a custom MSBuild target. So far I know how to do it.

But: In a VC++ project this metadata can be easily edited in a property window provided by Visual Studio. The definition Visual Studio uses comes from a rules xml file similar to the cl.xml I mentioned. How can I accomplish this in a C# project?

Comment: what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT: I don't have any additional information yet. Probably the only way to get this solved is to write an VS extension or create a custom [project system](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem). I don't have time to implement any of these. Or you could add a C++ project to your solution for this purpose only.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the correct way to define custom build actions?

You can use the [MSBuild Targets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171462.aspx) or [imported .targets file](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msbuild/2005/10/06/how-to-add-a-custom-build-action-to-visual-studio/) to define custom build actions in the project file.

> 1.I add an image file (.png) to the project
>   For this build action, you can use a [copy task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) in the target to copy the image file to the project folder:

```
    <Target Name="CopyFiles">  
    <Copy  
        SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)"  
        DestinationFolder="c:\MyProject\Destination"  
    />  
</Target>
```

> 2.I have a special image resource 'compiler' the transform the image (this compiler is defined using a msbuild target)

For this build action, you can import that msbuild target.

> 3.I want to change properties of the image file.

In the C# project, the properties of the image are also saved as MSBuild item metadata and forwarded to the MSBuild target.

[image]

Update:

> 4. In a VC++ project this metadata can be easily edited in a property window provided by Visual Studio. The definition Visual Studio uses comes from a rules xml file similar to the cl.xml I mentioned. How can I accomplish this in a C# project?

As far as I know we could not make custom items have additional metadata which be editable in the property window. This only can be applied to C++ and C++/CLI projects. .NET projects (C# and Visual Basic) don’t have that many options to be tweaked. You can refer to the [Sharing Project Properties in Visual C++](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319827/Sharing-project-properties-in-Visual-Cplusplus) for more detail.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: I've edited my question to provide some more information about what I'm looking for.

Comment: @alerosmile, If I understand correct, in the C# project, the metadata also can be easily edited in a properties window provided by Visual Studio. You can refer to the Properties window in the image  in the above answer. If not understand correct, please let me know for free and you can submit a new issue for a special attention.

Comment: My custom items have additional metadata which I want to be editable in the property window.

Comment: @alerosmile, I have updated my answer, you can check it. If above answer resolve your question, you can mark it as answer which is benefit for other communities who has the same problem. If not, you can update your question more detail or submit a new post. Thanks.